# Problems calculating sum of products with group_by

Tags: r, group-by, summarize

I would like to calculate the sum of a product by group, but I have different number of rows per each group
Here is my tibble

```
d<-c("2019-01-22", "2019-02-05", "2019-02-19" ,"2019-02-19" ,"2019-03-07" ,"2019-03-19" ,"2019-03-19" ,"2019-04-02" ,"2019-04-16",
        "2019-04-16" ,"2019-04-30" ,"2019-05-14" ,"2019-05-14" ,"2019-05-27" ,"2019-01-22" ,"2019-02-05" ,"2019-02-19",
        "2019-02-19" ,"2019-03-07" ,"2019-03-19" ,"2019-03-19" ,"2019-04-02" ,"2019-04-16" ,"2019-04-16" ,"2019-04-30" ,"2019-05-14",
        "2019-05-14" ,"2019-05-27")
mat<-rep(c("092000884483","092000884505"),each=14)
mung<-c("M" ,"M" ,"M" ,"S" ,"M" ,"M" ,"S" ,"M" ,"M" ,"S" ,"M" ,"M" ,"S" ,"M" ,"M" ,"M" ,"M" ,"S" ,"M" ,"M" ,"S" ,"M" ,"M" ,"S" ,"M" ,"M" ,"S" ,"M")
Tg<-c(5.42,4.40,6.39,7.79,3.77,4.65,3.26,5.42,4.17,5.33,4.65,6.43,9.68,8.10,6.68,4.46,6.37,8.90,3.79,5.59,6.66,6.06,6.28,9.48,6.00,6.24,10.48,8.31)
C4<-c(4.29, 5.07, 4.45, 4.15, 4.24, 3.78, 3.62, 4.16, 3.84, 3.54, 3.80, 3.77, 3.93, 3.70, 4.00, 4.22, 4.36, 4.04, 3.92, 3.69, 3.64, 4.27, 3.59, 3.91, 3.84, 3.74, 4.04, 3.01)

my_tbl<-tibble(Matricola=mat,datc=as.Date(d),Mung=mung,tg=Tg,C4_0=C4)
```

I want the sum of the product tg*C4_0 for each date and each Matricola.
If I calculate the sum of products by hand I do the following

```
my_tbl_t<-my_tbl%>%pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Matricola,datc),values_from =c(tg,C4_0),names_from = Mung )
#and calculate the sum of the prodcuts, conditioning to "missing" data
my_prd1<-my_tbl_t%>%mutate(C4_0ps1=case_when(is.na(tg_M)==F & is.na(tg_S)==F~(tg_M*C4_0_M+tg_S*C4_0_S),
                       is.na(tg_M)==F & is.na(tg_S)==T~(tg_M*C4_0_M),
                       is.na(tg_M)==T & is.na(tg_S)==F~(tg_S*C4_0_S)))
```

Alternatively, I can first calculate the product and the summarise within Matricola and date as follows

```
my_tbl%<>%mutate(C4_0p=C4_0*tg)
#and summarise by group
my_prd2<-my_tbl%>%group_by(Matricola,datc)%>%
  summarise(n=n(),C4_0ps2=sum(C4_0p,n.rm=T))
```

I expected that the C4_0ps1 in my_prd1 was the same that the variable C4_0ps2 in my_prd2, but it was not the case since the sum of products in my_prd2 is higher (1 unit) than that in my_prod1
I see that my_prd2 is still grouped by Matricola, but I can't understand why the sum of produts is wrong.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue. `my_tbl %>% mutate(C4_0ps1 = sum(C4_0 * tg), .by = c("Matricola", "datc"))` For me,  the order is different as there is grouping

Comment: It is still grouped by Matricola becuse `summarise` by  default only remove the last grouping.  You may need `.groups = 'drop'` in `summarise`

Comment: As an aside, `is.na()` returns TRUE or FALSE. `is.na(x) == T` is exactly the same as `is.na(x)`. Similarly, `is.na(x) == F` is the same as `!is.na(x)`. Your code will more readable if you don't do unnecessary `== T` and `== F`.

Comment: @akrun, thanks for the suggestions about is.na! Concerning the summarise problem, Do you obtain the same results (C4_0ps1=C4_0ps2?) running the first code (using case_when) or the second (using summarize)? I don't! Moreover, I Know that my_prd2 is grouped, but my_tbl is not. I was not able to reproduce `"my_tbl %>% mutate(C4_0ps1 = sum(C4_0 * tg), .by = c("Matricola", "datc")) "

Answer (score 0):

I found the error!  Instead of this code, which has a typo:

```
my_prd2 <- my_tbl %>% group_by(Matricola,datc) %>%
  summarise(n=n(),C4_0ps2=sum(**C4_0p,n.rm=T**))
```

I should write this, which has the proper `na.rm` argument:

```
my_prd2 <- my_tbl %>% group_by(Matricola,datc) %>%
  summarise(n=n(),C4_0ps2=sum(**C4_0p,na.rm=T**))
```